# Complex Analysis Qual Problem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having a difficult with the following qualifying exam question.  Any help would be awesome.  Thanks.

Find
$$
\sup\big\{|f(1)| \,\colon\, f\colon \Bbb C\setminus\{0\}\to \Bbb C \text{ is analytic and satisfies } |f(z)|\le 5|z|^{−\sqrt2} \big\}
$$

Comment: You are currently taking the qualifier AND posting this question using a smart phone?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Your post and title seem to suggest that this is a qualifying exam, and asking this would be highly unethical.

Comment: Its a past qual problem lol.

Comment: Hint: $z^2 f(z)$ has an analytic continuation to the entire plane, and vanishes at the origin. So show that $z f(z)$ is a bounded entire function....

Answer (score 1):

Following the hint by Greg Margin: let $g(z)=z^2 f(z)$. Since $\lim_{z\to 0}g(z)=0$, letting $g(0)=0$ we get an entire function. Then $h(z) = g(z)/z$ is also entire.  Since $|h(z)|\le 5|z|^{1-\sqrt{2}}$, it follows that $h$ vanishes at infinity, hence is bounded in $\mathbb C$. By Liouville's theorem $h$ is constant... and this constant can only be $0$.

Conclusion: the only such function $f$ is $f(z)\equiv 0$.